# Is it possible with libuv to create a client to another loop/thread from the server's loop/thread?

Tags: c, libuv

Suppose I've a main loop that handle all the new connection and several thread all running its own loop. I would like to distribute my clients to these loops.
Is it thread-safe to create a client in the main thread and pass to the init function another loop (that would be running on another thread), and start read ?
If no, how to achieve that ? (I guess an idle function that handle a queue of work would do the trick...)

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not safe.  If you want to achieve that you should use [uv_write2](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/stream.html?highlight=uv_write2#c.uv_write2) and send the handle to the other loop over a pipe.